# Listener listening without listener.ora

Tags: oracle, listener

I have an Oracle DB working in production for more than a year.
I have my listener working:

```
[oracle@base admin]$ lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0     
Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for Linux: Version 11.2.0.4.0 - Production
Start Date                02-NOV-2016 14:22:38
Uptime                    1 days 20 hr. 3 min. 13 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         /o/app/oracle/diag/tnslsnr/base/listener/alert/log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=base)(PORT=1521)))
Services Summary...
Service "BASE" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "BASE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "BASEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "BASE", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully
```

But **I have no `listener.ora`**:

```
ls /o/app/oracle/product/DB_11.2_SE/dbhome_2/network/admin/
samples  shrept.lst  tnsnames.ora
```

This is the content of my `tnsnames.ora`:

```
$ cat tnsnames.ora 
BASE =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.20.20.19)(PORT = 1521))
      (LOAD_BALANCE = yes)
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = BASE)
    )
  )


ORCL =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 10.20.20.20)(PORT = 1522))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = orcl)
    )
  )
```

How is this possible? As far as I know, for the listener to work, I have to have a `listener.ora` file.

I have another Oracle database installed, and if I execute `lsnrctl status`, in the output I can see a line containing `Listener Parameter File   /o/app/oracle/product/11.2/dbhome/network/admin/listener.ora`, and I am not seeing it here. Also I have executed `locate listener.ora`, and nothing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*"As far as I know, for the listener to work, I have to have listener.ora file."*

Starting with 8.1.5, listener.ora is optional for a default listener.

[Starting the Listener without a LISTENER.ORA (Doc ID 208968.1)](https://support.oracle.com/epmos/faces/DocContentDisplay?id=208968.1)

> ### Purpose
>
> To publicise the fact that from Oracle8i (8.1.5) onward, a
>   LISTENER.ORA is no longer required in order to start the Default
>   Oracle Net Listener.

Answer (score 6):

You don't need a `listener.ora`. The listener will happily start without one, but will just start without supporting any services. `pmon` will periodically register databases with the listener, but you can force registration manually.

Move the file away:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN>move listener.ora listener.foo
    1 file(s) moved.
```

Start the listener:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN>lsnrctl start

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-NOV-2016 13:50
:03

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Starting tnslsnr: please wait...

TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production
Log messages written to C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\host\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening on: (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                04-NOV-2016 13:50:08
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 0 min. 5 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\host\listener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))
The listener supports no services
The command completed successfully
```

Register the database with the listener:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN>sqlplus / as sysdba

SQL*Plus: Release 11.2.0.2.0 Production on Fri Nov 4 13:50:38 2016

Copyright (c) 1982, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.


Connected to:
Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Release 11.2.0.2.0 - 64bit Production

SQL> alter system register;

System altered.

SQL>
```

The listener now supports the database:

```
C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN>lsnrctl status

LSNRCTL for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Production on 04-NOV-2016 13:51
:20

Copyright (c) 1991, 2014, Oracle.  All rights reserved.

Connecting to (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=)(PORT=1521))
STATUS of the LISTENER
------------------------
Alias                     LISTENER
Version                   TNSLSNR for 64-bit Windows: Version 11.2.0.2.0 - Produ
ction
Start Date                04-NOV-2016 13:50:08
Uptime                    0 days 0 hr. 1 min. 15 sec
Trace Level               off
Security                  ON: Local OS Authentication
SNMP                      OFF
Listener Log File         C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\diag\tnslsnr\host\list  ener\alert\log.xml
Listening Endpoints Summary...
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=1521)))
  (DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=host)(PORT=8080))(Presentation=HTTP)(Session=RAW))
Services Summary...
Service "XEXDB" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
Service "xe" has 1 instance(s).
  Instance "xe", status READY, has 1 handler(s) for this service...
The command completed successfully

C:\oraclexe\app\oracle\product\11.2.0\server\network\ADMIN>
```